# the hash link not matched with nav menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, dom, event-handling

when I click on navbar item the hash link scroll event not matched with the correct nav menu item
I tried to change the 'scrollto' variable up or down but the problem still exists
[image: site navbar]

below is the code :

```
// Smooth scroll for the menu and links with .scrollto classes
  var scrolltoOffset = $('#header').outerHeight() - 21;
  var clicked = false;
  $('.nav-menu a, #mobile-nav a, .scrollto').on('click', function(e) {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
      var target = $(this.hash);
      debugger;
      if (target.length) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var scrollto = target.offset().top - scrolltoOffset;
        if ($(this).attr("href") == '#header') {
          scrollto = 0;
        }

        $('html, body').animate({
          scrollTop: scrollto
        }, 1500, 'easeInOutExpo');

        if ($(this).parents('.nav-menu').length) {
          $('.nav-menu .menu-active').removeClass('menu-active');
          $(this).closest('li').addClass('menu-active');
        }

        if ($('body').hasClass('mobile-nav-active')) {
          $('body').removeClass('mobile-nav-active');
          $('#mobile-nav-toggle i').toggleClass('fa-times fa-bars');
          $('#mobile-body-overly').fadeOut();
        }
       
        return false;
      }
    }
  });
```

this is the live site [innovators.com](https://innovators20.com/index.html)

Comment: If my answer suits you, can you accept the answer please?

Answer (score 0):

Easy fix. You are not scrolling enough.
Just scroll two pixels less: -21 => -23

```js
// Smooth scroll for the menu and links with .scrollto classes
  var scrolltoOffset = $('#header').outerHeight() - 23;
  var clicked = false;
  $('.nav-menu a, #mobile-nav a, .scrollto').on('click', function(e) {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
      var target = $(this.hash);
      debugger;
      if (target.length) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var scrollto = target.offset().top - scrolltoOffset;
        if ($(this).attr("href") == '#header') {
          scrollto = 0;
        }

        $('html, body').animate({
          scrollTop: scrollto
        }, 1500, 'easeInOutExpo');

        if ($(this).parents('.nav-menu').length) {
          $('.nav-menu .menu-active').removeClass('menu-active');
          $(this).closest('li').addClass('menu-active');
        }

        if ($('body').hasClass('mobile-nav-active')) {
          $('body').removeClass('mobile-nav-active');
          $('#mobile-nav-toggle i').toggleClass('fa-times fa-bars');
          $('#mobile-body-overly').fadeOut();
        }
       
        return false;
      }
    }
  });
```

Comment: no this does not solve the issue I tried that already